# Сортировка по глубине в r-tree

Tags: c++, boost

Использую r-tree из boost (geometry) для создания графической 2D сцены и возник такой вопрос: как сортировать объекты (box) по глубине. На данный момент r-tree хранит в качестве значений непосредственно box и указатель на item. Очевидно, что нужно добавить еще одно значение которое будет описывать глубину, но как это правильно сделать, чтобы запросы выдавали объекты в порядке определенном z-value, мне не очевидно. К тому же не совсем понятно как быть с объектами, которые имеют одинаковый z-value но при этом имеют пересечения - какой из них мы получим первым при запросе?

PS также интересно узнать есть ли удобный способ изменять положение объектов (их box) в rtree кроме как удалением и вставкой с новым значением box?

Comment: Глубина же зависит от положения наблюдателя. Зачем Вам это? у Вас полупрозрачные объекты?

Comment: Получаете все объекты - сортируете результат по z  и по порядку вставки

Comment: ну, к примеру, у меня есть два полигона один над другим и мне нужно отобразить их соответственно. Значит мне нужно создать запрос, который вернет сначала полигон, который сзади, а потом который спереди

Comment: @VTT рассматривал этот вариант, но в таком случае придеться сначала сохранить все объекты, полученный при запросе, а потом их сортировать. А теперь представте, что мне нужно получить лишь один объект по какой-то точке, который лежит сверху. Получается даже для такой операции мне все равно нужно взять полный список объектов, который пересекаются с этой точкой. Я думаю есть вариант получше